# JPA custom query returning List of nulls

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa

I have the following JPA query

```
@Query("SELECT a, b, c, d FROM table WHERE a in (:ids)", native = true)
List<Row> getRowByIDs(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

Row class has same mapped fields a,b,c,d from the query

When there is no matched rows from the query in the DB
it strangely returns a non null List but with one or more null items

When I print the result returned from java I get this

```
[null, null]
```

I have another similar api which returns empty list [] correctly

So I assume it is a problem with some mapping and/or db fields not matching?

Please help

Comment: Is this a JPA query or native? `@Query("SELECT a, b, c, d FROM table WHERE a in (:ids)")` Can you please post the exact query and the Entity (I guess `Row`?) supporting it (if any)?

Comment: I have edited the description ... I guess does not mind whatever fields i am pulling as long as they match in type. Just trying to see if someone else has had my same issue

Comment: Are you printing the value returned by the getRowByIDs JPA method? immediately after the method is executed?

Comment: Does your entity have the tag @Id on one of its attribute?

Comment: yes I print right after the query has executed and it prints [null]
And yes I have @Id on the entity

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the @Id was on the wrong attribute.
It looks like that spring jpa will return List with null elements for each record where the attribute annotated by @Id returned from the query is null
even if your where clause is on a non-key attribute